# Java Thread Affinity lib: Why is the Affinity set to 1 << 3?

Tags: java

I'm looking at the Java Thread Affinity lib (link below) and in an example the affinity is set using `1 << 3`. Does anyone know why this is?

```
AffinitySupport.setAffinity(1 << 3);
```

I would have thought it would be set to 1 or 2 for example on a 2 core machine as to say stay on core 1 or 2. I'm obviously missing something here.

Link: https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `AffinitySupport.setAffinity()` is a bit mask.

Setting the affinity to `1 << 3` allows the the thread to run on the logical CPU #3.

Comment: but the resulting value is 8 not 3. How does this map to CPU#3? thanks

Comment: @CodingQuant: Again, it's a bit mask. Bit 0 is for CPU#0, but 1 for CPU#1 and so on. A thread could be allowed to run on any of a set of CPUs.

Comment: but the method parameter is a long. So eight get passed.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax uses the left shift operator : http://processing.org/reference/leftshift.html 
So basically `1 << 3` means `1000` in binary so this is `8` in decimal.

Comment: but why use this instead of 8?